# How can I merge Color groups?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, swatches

I have several color groups that I use to conform illustrations to brand guidelines, most of them saved either in the Cloud, or in .ASE format.

Each color group has a little "folder" icon next to it, but I'd like them all in the same folder.

I would like to merge these color groups into just one ASE file - how can this be done?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click-shift-drag

- Click the first swatch in a group
- Hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key down
- Click the last swatch in a group
- Then click-drag them to another group

[image]

Then you can delete the empty folders.

Unless they've added a new feature in the bleeding edge version, this is all that is available. There's no automated functionality to merge color groups which I'm aware of at this time.

Comment: Thanks - for some reason I got the little  sign the first time I tried.